# Change default ssh:// behavior

Tags: terminal, ssh, tabs

Currently, the protocol handler `ssh://` opens the link in a new Terminal.app window. I'd like to default it so it opens it in a new tab instead. How can I change this behavior?

Backstory: I use Alfred and a workflow to open my ssh connections. [The workflow uses the `ssh://` handler to open the window.](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/826-ssh-with-smart-hostname-autocompletion/page-3#entry29632)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using some command-line tomfoolery:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

This is from a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171725/open-new-terminal-tab-from-command-line-mac-os-x) on a similar topic.

If you want you can even create a new URL handler (or replace the ssh:// one) with a shell script as described at [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418910/osx-defining-a-new-url-handler-that-points-straight-at-a-python-script).

EDIT1: you can get command line args from osascript by using something like the following (taken from the osascript man page):

```
a.scpt:
on run argv
    return "hello, " & item 1 of argv & "."
end run


% osascript a.scpt world
hello, world.
```

Comment: I'm close - I created an app from the AppleScript that opens up a new terminal tab. Using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) I set the ssh handler to this app. However, it doesn't then execute `ssh $PLACENAME` - it just opens the tab. So I have to pass in the params of the `ssh://` protocol to the AppleScript, I think. Got any ideas?

Comment: Can you have another line in your script to the effect of, 'tell application...... to keystroke "echo testing" '?

Comment: I can, but how do I get the url from the `ssh://` protocol?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's avail in the argv for whatever shell you're using; so if you're using bash, try using "echo $@" (before the osascript) to see what it looks like.

Comment: Oh, I just dropped it directly into an AppleScript app, rather than using shell. Does AppleScript have access to it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can access the applescript params... see edited answer.

Comment: Have any luck making this work?